# Apache HTTPClient Timeout at any moment

Tags: java, http, apache-commons

I'm making an HTTP connection using the Apache Common's HTTPClient.
The connection type is POST, and the client will be reading an output from the connection.
However I need to be able to abort the connection at any time regardless of the status of connection. What is the best way of doing this?
Is there a built in timeout?
Regards.

EDIT:
Just to clarify the my question:
I would like the user to be able to choose when the connection is to be cut.
In other words similar functionality to the parameter cURL:
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're instantiating the instance of httpClient using [HttpClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html), you can pass an instance of [RequestConfig](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html) to the builder, which inturn accepts 2 parameters.

`SocketTimeout` - Defines the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds, which is the timeout for waiting for data or, put differently, a maximum period inactivity between two consecutive data packets).

`ConnectTimeout` - Determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

`ConnectionRequestTimeout` - Returns the timeout in milliseconds used when requesting a connection from the connection manager. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

What you're looking for is **SocketTimeout**.

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT).setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT).build();
httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableAutomaticRetries().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).disableRedirectHandling().build();
```

You can take a look at [ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy.html). Refer to "2.6. Connection keep alive strategy" section of [page](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Sorry I didn't make myself clear enough I think.
I have tried your solution with socket timeout but it doesn't stop the connection.
Basically I will be receiving a constant stream of data through that connection but I want to be able to cut it after a user specified time (such as 10 seconds).

Comment: @GreenApples53 Okay, I misunderstood the question. Can you see if ConnectionKeepAliveStratergy helps? After the first response is received from the server you can use the keep-alive timeout to handle this. And before the response is received you can make use of socket timeout to achieve this. So I guess you need to mix both of them

Comment: I've currently implemented a solution that spawns a timer thread that simply aborts the connection after the specified time. I'm not sure if this is the best practice or not but it seems to work for me. Do you think there will be any problems with this? Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [DefaultHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html), it accepts [HttpParams](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpParams.html) where you can provide connection related settings.

SO_TIMEOUT is the SocketTimeout - Defines the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds, which is the timeout for waiting for data or, put differently, a maximum period inactivity between two consecutive data packets).

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
httpParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
httpParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
DefaultHttpClient backend = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

A better way of doing it is by using HttpClientBuilder as @Bandi Kishore suggested. or by making use of `PoolingClientConnectionManager` which accepts these settings directly using setters.